# Create war file in grails using GGTS

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite

I have done a small application in Grails, and now I need to generate a war file to test it on server. I generated a war using command grails:war. It has generated the file but named it as `myapp-01.war`. I don't want this, I need a war where the file name should be same as the project; like `myapp.war`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`grails war myapp.war`

Additional options: http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Command%20Line/war.html